# I am trying to get an entry as an integer in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import tkSimpleDialog

def blank(row, column):
    blank = Label(text=" ")
    blank.grid(row=row, column=column)

def prtent():
    distEnt.getint()
    print distEnt

root = Tk()

#title

root.title("Trip Time Calculator")

label = Label(text="Trip Time Calculator", font=50)
label.grid(columnspan=50)

blank(2, 0)
blank(3, 0)

#distance

distLabel = Label(text="What is your distance?")
distLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)

distEnt = Entry()
distEnt.grid(row=4, column=1)

blank(5, 0)

#speed

speedLabel = Label(text="What is your speed?")
speedLabel.grid(row=6, column=0)

distEnt = Entry()
distEnt.grid(row=6, column=1)

blank(7, 0)

#test button

button = Button(text="Done", command=prtent)
button.grid(row=8, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

My problem is when I enter a number into a field in my GUI all that is returned in the console is ".42880656". The application I am trying to make is where you can enter your distance and speed and get an approximate ETA in Python 2.7.

Comment: Why is your returned number not correct? "Because it's not an integer" - well if you force it to be, per standard conversion rules it'd be `0`, and I suspect that's not what you want either.

Comment: That is true but for any number I put in whether it be a float or an integer it still returns ".42880656"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print distEnt
```

This is your problem... `distEnt` is an Entry(), not a number.  I believe it should look like...

```
dist = distEnt.getint()
print dist
```

For a bit more explanation...

the Entry() distEnt is the actual component that is displayed on your screen.  Fetching it as an integer doesn't make any sense- it is a textbox.  It has a helpful function .getint() that returns the *contents* of that text box formatted as an integer.  If you want to do something with those contents, you fetch that number and put it in a variable, and then use that variable to do your business logic.  If you set that variable equal to something else, you'll lose your reference to the textbox in the GUI.

The error you actually saw there is a Python thing.  You can inherit variables from the next scope up without doing anything...

```
a_number = 7
def a_func():
    print a_number # 7
```

will work.  However, if you try to *assign* to that variable, it will assume you must have made a mistake (why are you trying to mutate global state in a function?!?) and throw an error.  You have to inherit the global variable with the global keyword in that case to tell the interpreter that yes, you really do mean that.

```
a_number = 7
def a_func():
    print a_number
    a_number = 42 # exception


a_number = 7
def a_func():
    global a_number
    print a_number # 7
    a_number = 42 
f()
print a_number # 42
```

One further point- if you ASSIGN to it BEFORE you mutate it, you won't get the exception... because the variable name in the function scope is a brand new local that has no relation to the global variable.  You only get the exception if you try to use the global variable before mutating.

```
a_number = 7
def a_func():
    a_number = 42
    print a_number # 42
f()
print a_number # 7
```

Comment: I tried that and I get this `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/bcmwolverine/Desktop/Home-Made Apps/testing2.py", line 10, in prtent
    distEnt = distEnt.getint()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'distEnt' referenced before assignment`

Comment: you don't want to override distEnt with the integer you just fetched.  Create a new variable to store the integer, and then print that.  or if you really want to do it in one line, `print distEnt.getint()`